# Update Formula on Custom Field via API

Tags: api, formula

I am about to add a lot of Formula fields to our opportunity objects, but they will all be pretty much the same (calculating the business hours between 2 datetimes)

The only way I currently know how to do this is to go through the web interface and create them all manually, substituting in the field names of the timestamps I want to compare as I go.

Clearly this is going to be tedious, and it is likely that I will break something, and it will be incredibly hard to go back and change.

Before I embark on this endeavour, I wondered if it was possible to use the API to set the Formula for these fields externally.  So that i can programatically add more, and do all the other fun things that DRY code lets you do.

-Alex

Comment: Have you seen the Metadata API yet? I think that's what you're looking for. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/

Comment: To add on to Mike Chale's comment, Andrew Fawcett has written a nifty wrapper around the Metadata API for calling it via Apex.  https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Answer (score 3):

Writing Apex code to execute the metadata API to simplify field creation seems rather the long way round on this one.

The [Force.com IDE](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) would work well for this. I would create the first formula field in the UI, download the object metadata, and then copy & paste the field's XML, altering the field names as you go, and then just save the .object file back to Salesforce.

Within the UI, [Schema Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=schema_builder.htm&siteLang=en_US), is a lot faster for repetitive field creation than the regular wizard, but still not a bargain.

The other tool that came to mind, the [Force CLI](http://www.wadewegner.com/2013/11/a-command-line-interface-for-forcecom/), doesn't yet support formula field creation, but is great for most other kinds of fields.

Comment: oooooooh, shiny